# Reading from file works in iPhone 6.1 Simulator, but not in iPhone device (iOS 6.1.3)

Tags: ios

I have a "Write" button that takes whatever in a Textfild, and appends to a designated file. I also have a "Read" button that reads from the content of the designated file, and displays it on the screen. The "Write" button calls writeDataToFile:(id)sender, and the "Read" button calls  readDataFromFile:(id)sender.

The problem is that the following simple code works fine on iPhone 6.1 Simulator (Xcode 4.6.2), but does not display anything in a read device, e.g., iPod with iOS 6.1.3.

I suspect the problem is something related to encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding. However, I tried NSUTF16StringEncoding and NSUTF32StringEncoding, and it still didn’t work on the real device (but disply scrambled words on Simulator).

Where did I do wrong? I would appreciate very much if somebody can give me some pointers.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    _fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.txt"];
}


- (IBAction)writeDataToFile:(id)sender {
    NSString *str = tfData.text;
    str = [str stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n"];
    _fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:_fileName];
    [_fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    //convert NSString to NSData
    [_fileHandle writeData: [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [_fileHandle  closeFile];

    [tfData resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)readDataFromFile:(id)sender {
    [tfData resignFirstResponder];
    //lbOut is a UILabel
    lbOut.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:_fileName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
}
```

Comment: I recommend checking the paths you are writing the file to:  iOS imposes a strict sandbox on the device, whereas the on the simulator, the application's directory is simply in the host's filesystem and you can write anywhere.   The reason it see no errors?  Because you aren't checking the return from *any* of the API calls you use, and sending messages on NULL pointers is a no-op in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I did create a a file path under the sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is with the binding of _fileHandle. I declare this public variable, and binds it with a NSFileHandle associated with the file I intended to write using
[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:_fileName]. I intended to keep using the _fileHandle from different ViewControllers without the need to bind it with the file every time I use it. It resulted the problem I described (i.e., works fine on Simulator, but not on real device).

Once I re-bind _fileHandle with NSFileHandle initialization every time I use it, it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to diagnose whether the file exists when you try to read from it. You can do this with `NSFileManager`. Also check whether the file has the right size (or at least a non-zero size).

Also, have you checked whether `stringWithContentsOfFile` actually returns a string? If an error occurs it will return `nil` and not raise an exception. If you get `nil` you can pass an `NSError` object to `stringWithContentsOfFile` and it will let you know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking your return values. If I had to make a guess I would say that the file at `_fileName` does not exist. If the file doesn't exist `fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:` will return nil. And each subsequent call on the fileHandle will fail silently.

So you should check if `fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:` actually returns a fileHandle. If it doesn't, create a fileHandle by using `fileHandleForWritingAtPath:`.

In a similar way you should check if the conversion to NSData has failed. I used `NSParameterAssert`, which will crash your app if stringData is nil, because I think there is no way to recover from a failed NSString conversion. If you think there is a way to recover from this error replace the `NSParameterAssert` with a `if (!stringData)` statement.

```
_fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:_fileName];
if (!_fileHandle) {
    NSLog(@"File does not exist at path \"%@\". Create it.", _fileName);
    _fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:_fileName];
}
// should have a valid fileHandle here
[_fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];

NSData *stringData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSParameterAssert(stringData); // will raise an exception if stringData is nil
[_fileHandle writeData:stringData];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. After checking, I found the _fileName does exist. It just did not write anything on the file as it was supposed to.